# If statement in algebra

Tags: puzzle

Is there a form to if statement in algebra . Or a way to do it . For example
Let X , y ,z be 3 numbers . (X is always less than y )

If X/y = 4/5 then z = 1 else z = 0 
I thought of a way and it was an equation like that . 
(X/y-1) - (X mod y-1 )/y-1 
It worked 
but some time y-n is negative so it does not work .
So is there an alternative or an edit on this equation to do that 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps a [piecewise-defined function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise) is what you have in mind?

Comment: You could use the [kronecker delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) and say $z=\delta_{x/y,~4/5}$... perhaps you want a more general method to follow, in which case Peter's comment should be able to handle any if-then clause you can think of.  (*kronecker delta is defined as $\delta_{i,j}=\begin{cases}1&\text{iff}~i=j\\ 0&\text{iff}~i\neq j\end{cases}$*)

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking about . Thanks you both :-)